# Count length of letter string

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that look like that (DNA sequence in fasta format):

```
>sequence_name1
ATCGTGATNNNNNNNNAGTCGATCGGATTCT
>sequence_name2
NNNNATGTNNATGTCCNNNNNNN
```

I want to count the length of gaps, that is the length of N strings.
For instance, in the first sequence the length is 8.
In the second sequence, I have a gap of 4, another of 2 and another of 7.

It would be great if I could obtain a table with gap length density that is a table stating that I have X gaps that have a length of 1, X that have a length of 2, and so on :

```
1 X
2 X
3 X
...
```

Any idea how to do that ?

Thank you !

Mu

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Just as a tip, normally in genome analysis researchers use the statistical language R. It might be a good investment to learn, or at least add it as a tag, so that people think of answering in that language too ;)

Comment: Presbitero, I already use R but as for Bash I didn't know how to do that !! If you have an answer with R, I will be happy !!!

Answer (score 1):

Awk OK? Try something like this:

```
awk -F'[^N]*' '
  !/^>/ {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      g=length($i)
      if(g>m)m=g
      A[g]++
    }
  } 
  END {
    for(i=1; i<=m; i++) print i, A[i]+0
  }
' file
```